# Measuring very High Frequency with STM32F10x

Tags: frequency, high-frequency, stm32f10x

with which software package I can measure the frequency of an external signal with very high frequency? and is there any especial hardware for this goal in STM32F10x micros? 
Thanks;

Comment: You mean like the 16 bit counters with input capture TMI1?

Comment: How high do you mean when you say "very high"?

Comment: For future reference: "Very high frequency" means different things to different people, to a power supply designer, a few tens of MHz might be considered "*very high*" whereas a radio astronomer might consider 900GHz to be "very high" while an electrical (not electronic) engineer might sometimes call a few kHz a "very high frequency" (well, 1kHz *is* the *20th* harmonic of 50Hz mains after all)

Answer (score 0):

First of all what means

> very high frequency

The best approach to measure frequencies with the STM32x is to use the external Tim input to count the rising edges of your signal.

Every low-high transition will increment the internal count register of your desired Timer.

You will then have to initialize an accurate internal timebase, as example an other timer, which will reads the externally triggered Timer Count Register.

If you have the timebase and the counts, then you can calculate the applied signals frequency. Make sure that the applied signals are within the specs of the stm32.